# Is it correct to say "other alternatives"?

Tags: redundancy

We often see people writing:

> I have other alternatives for you.

Isn't it redundant to use the word "other" with alternatives as *the word "alternative" itself* implies *other options or ways*?

Comment: Let's say B is an alternative to A. You've been considering A and B. Now C and D show up. They are indeed "other alternatives" to the original you've been considering.

Comment: It would still be right if one said, "I have alternatives for you." In this case, the alternatives would be the other options like B, C & D."

Comment: Some people would be very pedantic and say that there can only be one alternative, because it means "the other" not "an other". I'm not quite that stuck in Latin that I'd be one of those people, but I'm not far off :)

Comment: @DharmeshBhatia Welcome to EL&U. If you want your message to be sent to a specific person, you can use "@ID as I am doing it in this comment. You wanted to send your comment to Robusto, right?

Comment: @Rathony: I may be mistaken, but I suspect SE's inbox notification is smart enough to ping Robusto for OP's comment above, on the grounds that since he was the only prior poster, he's the only credible "intended recipient".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely a pleonasm, but that doesn't mean that it is always bad. It can be used for emphasis or one may have mentioned some alternatives already and these are more alternatives. Stylistically it is annoying.

Answer (score 3):

[*Other*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/other) is defined in Merriam-Webster:

> used to refer to all the members of a group except the person or thing
>   that has already been mentioned
>
> : in addition to the person or thing that has already been mentioned
>
> : different or separate from the person or thing that has already been
>   mentioned

If the person is saying:

> There are other-than-previously-mentioned alternatives.

or

> There are alternatives in addtion to the altermatives I mentioned
>   before.

**Other** is *not redundant* at all.

It simply means "***not the same, different***"

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Merriam-Webster, 'Alternative,' as a noun (which it is in this particular sentence), means 'option' or 'choice,' and not 'another option.' This would imply that using 'other' with 'alternative' is completely fine and in fact, correct.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, "other alternatives" is redundant. [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alternative) defines  the noun "alternative" as follows:

> The remaining option; something available after other possibilities have been exhausted.

If you feel compelled to use the word "other", what about "I have other option(s) for you"?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Your own link to wiktionary provides other definitions for _alternative_ which allow the use of _other_ as a modifier.